New Instagram Graph API: How to get the username of a comment with the "Instagram API with Instagram Login"
With the new Instagram Graph API (graph.instagram.com) it is not possible to get the username of comments.
The API is also known as "Instagram API with Instagram Login" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-platform/instagram-api-with-instagram-login)
When I specify the field "username" the API does not return a username: https://graph.instagram.com/\<media_id\>/comments?fields=text,username&access_token=\<access_token\>
Response:
...
{
"text": "The text of the comment",
"id": "1234567891234"
},
...

When I specify the field from it returns this error:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Permissions error",
    "type": "IGApiException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "B65VxFeFQTrxLPcgbSb6c3N"
  }
}

It works with the old Facebook Graph API but not with the new one (graph.instagram.com).

Does the user field give you anything?

Nope, the only fields returning anything so far are:
like_count,text,hidden,id,media,timestamp,replies

Using From in the Fields works for me. Try playing around with permissions and it would work.

Thanks for your answer!
I have all permission for instagram_business_*, including instagram_business_manage_comments.
But still it is not working. Do you really use graph.instagram.com, or graph.facebook.com?

I am using graph.instagram only. These are the permissions I have set - instagram_basic
instagram_content_publish
instagram_manage_comments
instagram_manage_insights
instagram_shopping_tag_products
pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement

from is also works for me. But it's doesn't work with replies to comments.
@DakshKapur how did you get it?
username who reply to comments are not being retrieved. Instead, the API only provides limited information, such as: timestamp, ID, and the text.

Since you at least get the text, do you have any idea why I always get an empty array (there are comments and it is from one of the test users I gave access to):
{
    "data": [],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "before": "QVFIUk11RnBiUzBSeHdHLXFCamtWaVVwN3Y3dFltT1U2ZA3RTdWc3WVQxS09QU19UVnVIOVlYbVRMZA1pQMWd2T2lXODF1YVdzNk5jQVRzX3RibGNnamhLdmJn",
            "after": "QVFIUjE2RjAzVUoxcjBVZAmdhaEFxeVZAmQTRHcEJDX1M4ZAXJIcmt1T3UybEJDQWwyOU9tT2lENnVkVkJVZAjgzbExVODVMd2tja1BDbElnb3JzaU9teXlaQktn"
        },
        "next":"..."
    }
}


You have to switch to „Live“ in your app to access comments.

Try this:
media_id = posts_data["data"][0]["id"]
fields = "fields=comments{from,parent_id,text,timestamp,username}"
fb_url = f"{FBBASEURL}/{media_id}?{fields}&access_token={token}"

(same as graph API facebook login but works with IG with IG login)
--
output
{'comments': {'data': [{'from': {'id': '1481093006109434',
     'username': 'code_with_ssk'},
    'text': 'ai',
    'timestamp': '2024-09-14T17:09:19+0000',
    'id': '18151893334326014'},
}}

